# spring mvc 3 hibernate exception

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, google-app-engine

I have a problem with the mysql connection, I use JPA / Hibernate 4 with spring mvc 3 / google app engine. I have the error locally or on the google app engine server.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [S1000]; error code [0]; Could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:651)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.findByLogonemailAndPwd(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1739)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274)
```

**note**: Before the application works very well I reboot machine the error is appears.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

probably you haven't started your mysql server, eg: it's setup as a manual service / executable you have to run first

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at your configuration file to see the hostname of mysql server.